# Jmeter- attempt to finish threads in a time limit

Tags: multithreading, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

So my requirements state that the system should be able to process 10000 requests  in 1 hour. So that means i should run a tests that sees how fast it can process 10k requests(not concurent users). I have never had to do such a thing as my requierements were aways in concurent users. Can someone tell me what thread group to use and how it should be set up to do this particular task. Again the endgame is not to reach 10k concurent users but to run 10k requests and see how fast they can complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to finish in 3600 seconds 10000 requests.

Assuming that ( last) request takes maximun 100 seconds you should execute with Thread group defined with maximum [ramp up][1] = 3500 while Number of Threads = 10000

> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish

I suggest start with Ramp up = 3500 and decrease number until requests will start to failed.

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen.

Another option is using JMeter plugin [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)

> simplified approach for configuring threads schedule. It is intended to maintain the level of concurrency, which means starting additional during the runtime threads if there's not enough of them running in parallel. Unlike standard Thread Group, it won't create all the threads upfront, so extra memory won't be used. It's a good repacement for Stepping Thread Group, since it allows threads to finish their job gracefully.

In your case not concurrent user for an hour:

```
Target Concurrency = 1 (not concurrent) 

Ramp up Time - 60 (minutes)

Ramp up Steps Count  1

Hold Target Rate Time 60 (minutes)

Thread Iteration Limit 1 (not concurrent)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion calculating how much time in seconds i need was my backup i was wondering isnt there a smarter way to tell jmeter. Run these threads as fast as they can finish once 1 thread finishes close it and continue until all threads are done.

Comment: add more option to execute

Answer (score 0):

10 000 requests in one hour is something like 166.6 requests per minute or 2.7 requests per second.

You can use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) in order to limit JMeter's throughput to the given numbers and see whether it will be able to complete 10k requests in 1 hour or not.

The test run may be shorter as if you see [throughput](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) metric going beyond 2.7 requests per second - most likely the system under test will not be able to cope with the load.

Once you will get confidence that your system can handle 10k requests in one hour you can increase the throughput to see if/where/when it breaks.